# Cant run cypress using UI

Tags: cypress, upgrade

I can run my scripts using editor in headless mode but scripts are failing when tried to run using cypress UI

Getting error

From Node.js Internals:Error: socket hang upat connResetException (node:internal/errors:690:15)at Socket.socketOnEnd (node:_http_client:471:24)at Socket.emit (node:events:406:36)at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1331:13)at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:22)

Try to upgrade cypress version from 9.4.1. to 10.1.0 but again getting error

PS C:\Users\hshah\cypress> npm install --save-dev cypress@10.0.3
npm ERR! must provide string spec

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\hshah\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-20T05_10_05_825Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\hshah\cypress>

Not sure what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove your `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder.
2. In your `package.json`, change the cypress version to 10.1.0
3. Run the command `npm cache clean --force`
4. Then run the command `npm install`. This will install all the dependencies listed in your `package.json` file.

Comment: Thank you Alapan. I have tried above steps. But still when I run npm install, I am getting error npm ERR! must provide string spec

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hshah\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-21T01_33_53_547Z-debug.log.